# How can I modify a javascript event in a PDF file programmatically?

Tags: javascript, pdf, events, itext

My PDF file has an event attached to a button. I need to be able to modify that event programmatically. I tried this way using iTextSharp, but it didn't change the javascript in the new file:

```
var pdfReader = new PdfReader(originalPdfDocumentPath);

pdfReader.RemoveUsageRights();

var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(
    newPdfDocumentPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None), 
    '\0', true);

var originalXml = pdfReader.AcroFields.Xfa.DomDocument.InnerXml;

var newXml = originalXml.Replace(
    "Table2.Row1.instanceManager.removeInstance(1)", 
    "Table2._Row1.removeInstance(this.parent.parent.index)");

// Unfortunately, this line does nothing.
pdfStamper.AcroFields.Xfa.DomDocument.InnerXml = newXml; 
pdfStamper.Close();
pdfReader.Close();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please use code blocks around your code.

Comment: Javascript attached to a button and the xml for xfa forms are two different things. This example might help you on your way: http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/actions-and-annotations/itext7-how-add-onmouseover-javascript-action-textfield

Comment: The script I need to modify is inside a dynamic form, inside the XFA. The old script shows in the variable originalXml, in my example. What I would need to know is how to replace the Xfa.DomDocument.InnerXml with my newXml string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it works if, instead of changing the XML directly, I change the DomDocument and mark the XFA as changed. Below is the corrected code:

```
var pdfReader = new PdfReader(originalPdfDocumentPath);

pdfReader.RemoveUsageRights();

var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newPdfDocumentPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None), '\0', true);

var originalXml = pdfReader.AcroFields.Xfa.DomDocument.InnerXml;

var newXml = originalXml.Replace("Table2.Row1.instanceManager.removeInstance(1)", "Table2._Row1.removeInstance(this.parent.parent.index)");

/* New Code */
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(newXml);

pdfStamper.AcroFields.Xfa.DomDocument = doc;
pdfStamper.AcroFields.Xfa.Changed = true;
/* End of New Code */

pdfStamper.Close();

pdfReader.Close();
```

I should note that, even though this code changes the javascript in the PDF file, it also disables the extended features in Adobe Acrobat Reader. You can find more information regarding this here:

http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/why-do-i-get-error-saying-use-extended-features-no-longer-available

> "The problem is related to whether or not your document is Reader Enabled. Reader-enabling can only be done using Adobe software. It is a process that requires a digital signature using a private key from Adobe. When a valid signature is present, specific functionality (as defined in the usage rights when signing) is unlocked in Adobe Reader.
>   You change the content of such a PDF, hence you break the signature."